# Make auto layout expand to left when contents grow?

Tags: figma

I have an auto layout that I'm trying to "fix" to the right. So when the items within the layout become wider and make the auto layout itself wider, I want it to expand to the left not to the right.

[image]

Currently its expanding to the right. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I have this hacky way.

- Horizontally flip the layer (Shift + H)
- If they are symmetric shapes, then should work fine.
- If they are text layers, then you would have to individually flip back your text layers horizontally again. (See Frame 4 vs Frame 5) below.

[image]

Other than that, maybe some Figma Plugins such as these would help with your situation:
[image]